# MongooseServerSelectionError nothing i do is working

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

i already did all these:
Restarted the MongoDB service.
Replaced localhost by 0.0.0.0.
Replaced local host by 127.0.0.1:27017

i already have node installed in my pc so i went ahead with node instead of yarn like in video
when connecting the database the video shows the "database connected" message but i am having some issues

this is my app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

//middlewares
app.use(express.json()); //json format
app.use(morgan("tiny")); //when you hit any API endpoint it will log in the console. 
//endpoint with request and time it took to send back response


//routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello world");
});



//server configurations
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, async () => {     //async bc using await keyword
    try {
        await connectDB();       //we dont want app to be executed before app successfully connects to database
        console.log(`server listening on port: ${PORT}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and this is the db.js code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    return mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost/contact_mern")
    .then(() => console.log(`connection to database established...`))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));   
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

i tried changing the localhost to various other things like 27017 and 27017.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.27017 but nothing worked and instead of that standard message all i got was

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\ASH\Visual Studio Code\bharatintern internship\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:805:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\ASH\Visual Studio Code\bharatintern internship\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:780:11)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (C:\ASH\Visual Studio Code\bharatintern internship\server\app.js:24:9) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
server listening on port: 8000
```

on my terminal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be from your mongodb server. Check if your MongoDB server is started and listening on port 27017 which is the default. Also check if you have the required data folder.